# Creating a line along an existing polyline from a point

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, line, polyline-creation

I have a large data set of points, all of which lie on a river network and have x, y co-ordinates. I want to calculate the slope of the river channel at each point from the underlying DEM by taking the elevation at each point and the elevation of a point on the network 1km upstream. The best way I can think of doing this is by creating a line upstream from each point that stops when it reaches 1km away (obviously the line will not be straight in most instances), then create a point at the end of that line. I guess the flow direction or accumulation layer could be used to draw the line in the correct direction (upstream) from each point but I don't know where to start!

Comment: You can use [Extract multi values to points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000002s000000) to get the elevation at certain points. Your method of getting the upstream point is not likely to work; one point downstream have many different points/routes upstream. Even if you select the steepest path your not guaranteed to end up with a point that lies within your river at 1 km upstream. Maybe you can create a line feature in the river to trace backwards and pick a point close to it?

Comment: Have a look at [RivEX](http://www.rivex.co.uk) it has tools for generating u/s and d/s line segments based upon points snapped to a river network.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little difficult because of the branching nature of stream networks.  Over 1km you will likely need your solution to be able to make a choice of which branch/tributary to trace up.  I suggest calculating Horton stream order for your stream lines and then dissolving features based on the Horton order field.  Once that is done you can create a point 1km upstream in python by using the [shapely](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely) library and the [.interpolate()](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html?highlight=interpolate#object.interpolate) function.

To calculate Horton order you can use [GRASS](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/R.stream.*_modules#r.stream.order) or I have a messy [script to calculate Horton order](https://github.com/spaceof7/WFC-GIS/blob/master/horton.py).